# Why use or not use java 7 to make JAVA EE applications

Tags: java, java-7

Java 6 is a stable version of this programming language. But I would like to upgrade to the current version java 7. At this time, is recommended to use java 7 in production? Where I can find updated information about the possible problems that I can get if I upgrade to java 7?

Comment: Java 1.4 is also "a stable version of this programming language". And some poor folks are still stuck with that. Don't be that guy (in a few years).

Comment: Java 7 has been the current version of Java for a while now, and Java 6 has been [outdated](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) since Feb 2013, so no reason to use Java 6 anymore.

Comment: C'mon, Java 7 is stable and kicking around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why use or not use java 7 to make JAVA EE applications

This was added later.  The main reason not to use Java 7 is that your web server might not support Java 7. e.g. some very expensive EE servers haven't got round to migrating to Java 7 in the 2.5 years since it was available for testing.  IMHO this is pretty poor given the money they charge.

> At this time, is recommended to use java 7 in production?

AFAIK, Java 7 is more recommended than Java 6, give it is not supported for free any more.

Java 7 is a requirement for the G1 collector, Java Mission Control and JavaFX 2.

Note: with Java 8 coming out soon with many new/powerful features, I expect many developers will be using it by the middle of 2014.

> Where I can find updated information about the possible problems that I can get if I upgrade to java 7?

Most of the problems have been around client applet security.

https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/migrating_from_java_se_6

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/adoptionGuide/

http://www.slideshare.net/myfear/practical-migration-to-java-7

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/Architecture/WASv7_JavaCompatibility/player.html (note this has audio)

Comment: +1 for the valuable links you attached. Haven't seen them before.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the convenient improvements to the language in 7 and the fact that 6 is no longer supported, there were some very serious security issues with 1.6 that caused Apple (amongst others) to drop default support for Java.

Those issues were fixed with 1.7 and for that reason alone, you should update.

Two blogs detailing the controversy below;

http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/apple-drops-java-in-latest-os-x-security-release/
http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerability/apple-removes-default-java-support-in-br/240009305

Answer (score 3):

You should use a supported Java version. Have a look at the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). Java 6 has reached "END OF PUBLIC UPDATES" - so it is not supported anymore.

At least you should run your Java 6 code on a Java 7 VM.

Comment: +1 making sure that your code *can* run without a problem on Java 7 is a *very important* step towards moving to the new platform fully. Do that *as early as possible* (there's really almost no reason not to do it and it *usually* costs little to nothing).

Answer (score 0):

it is dependent, if you are going to make an application for android you may use Java 6, but if your creating a application for desktop it is recommended to use Java 7.
Java 7 have some improvement of course, specially on file io, which is .nio package.